# How to assign local variable value to variable of a function [Three.js] JSON Loader

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, webgl

I am trying to load a external JSON model to the scene, and trying to put its value to the variable named head, and consequently want to add it to the scene.

What I did is, like this

```
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

    this.head = loader.load( "eagle2.js", function( geometry ) {

        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial(), head;
        head = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        head.scale.set( 200, 200, 200 );
        head.position.y = 0;

        return head;
    } );

    this.mesh.add(this.head);
```

what I like to do is Load the JSON model and put all the mesh to the head variable of the function that i am currently in. However when I run the above code it shows type error in firebug. The Model load successfully but the error is like

> TypeError: a is undefined
>   Three.js
>   Line 55

What should I do to fix this error?

Comment: You would not have a problem if you move this.mesh.add(this.head); inside the function instead of returning the head variable. What is happening is that head is allocted inside the callback function and goes out of scope when you return, so you dont have access to it.

Comment: when i do so it again throws error saying
TypeError: this is undefined
Line 215

it doesnt understand this inside that callback function

Comment: what you need to do is add "var scope = this;" just before you call the loader.load and then use the variable scope inside the callback. ie. scope.mesh.add (head) as inside the callback the "this" has been redifined.

Comment: it works :). thank you gaitat for the response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

method load of JSONLoader returns nothing. Instead it makes an async call to the server and returns data in the callback function, so right usage should look like this:

```
var self = this;
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

loader.load( "eagle2.js", function( geometry ) {

    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial(), head;
    head = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    head.scale.set( 200, 200, 200 );
    head.position.y = 0;

    self.head = head;
    self.mesh.add(head);
} );
```